# Validate formData with image in Backend

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, validation

I have a problem to keep validating  the data  I send from ReactJs in the Backend (Spring Boot). I have to include an image, so the annotation RequestBody it's been changed by RequestParam and the Ojbect is received by @Valid Product product. All validations I use to have in the back as in @unique=true won't work anymore.

¿how can i use two both Request? RequestBody and RequestParam?

Backend

`@PostMapping("/addProduct") public ResponseEntity<?> createWithFoto(@Valid Product product, BindingResult result, @RequestParam("imageFile") MultipartFile image)`

Frontend

```
export const save = async (imageData) => {   
    try {
        return await usersApi.post(`${BASE_URL}/products/addProduct`, imageData,{
            'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data', 'Accept':'*/*'});
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
}
```

ImageData contains with append all data from the product, plus the image.

```
        imageData.append('productName', productName);
        imageData.append('description', description);
        imageData.append('price', price);

        imageData.append('imageFile', file);
```

Thanks for your helping

I expect to validate from the backend the annotation in the entity as in  @Column(unique = true).

Comment: You want to validate imageName is unique or not before saving the entity that contains info about image?